How can I know how many space is in one tab character in a text file?
I have a text file like this:
0.  ----.----1----.----2----.----3----.----4
1. |Hello1
2. |    Hello2
3. |        Hello3
4. |Hello4              Hello5
5. |                    Hello6
6. |        Hello7      Hello8

I want to count indentations at the start of the line before any other characters.
This is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    bool valid;
    int index = 0;
    int indent = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream file(argv[1]);
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        valid = true;
        while (true)
        {
            if (index >= line.length())
            {
                break;
            }
            if (valid && line[index] == ' ')
            {
                indent++;
            }
            else if (valid && line[index] == '\t')
            {
                indent += 4;
            }
            else if (line[index] == 'H') //example for other characters
            {
                // do something with character
                valid = false;
            }
            index++;
        }
        cout << indent << endl;
        index = 0;
        indent = 0;
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}

The output:
0
4
8
0
20
8

It works fine now.
But I know sometimes the tab character might be 2 or 8 spaces.
How can I know how much space is in one tab character in a text file?

Tab spacing is dependent on the terminal and its settings. There's no one single "standard tab". Though in most terminals I have seen the default is 8. You could hard-code the width of the tabs, like you currently do (in a rather bad way, where it's not easy to change); Or you could take the tab spaces as an argument to the program and if not provided use some decent default (I would recommend 8).

It's entirely up to the program that renders the file. It's not a property of the file itself, but of the viewer.

TLDR you can't, a tab is a single (ASCII) symbol and can expand into any kind of indentation.

Also note that for terminals, a tab doesn't insert a number of spaces, it moves to the next tab stop which is a fixed vertical position. Assuming a tab width of 8, then printing one character and then a tab will move the cursor 7 spaces. If you print 6 characters and then a tab the cursor will move only 2. That means that your indent += 4; statement will not work as usually expected for tabs.

It sounds like an XY problem to me. can you tell us more specifically where you want to use this situation?

What Aria is referring to is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

I try to make an lexical analyzer for programming language and i want it to be like haskell which use indent to determine block of scopes if i know it correctly

Looks like haskell uses 8 spaces for a tab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751929/when-to-use-tabs-and-when-to-use-spaces-in-haskell

I just set my tab size to 1, so it doesn't matter if I use tabs or spaces.

"I know sometimes the tab character might be 2 or 8 spaces." -- Then you know that what you ask does not have a definite answer. It depends on how you view the file, sometimes on your viewer's settings.

@kamrannasirizad i want it to be like haskell which use indent to determine block of scopes if i know it correctly" -- Then it's up to you to define how many spaces a tab character represents in your programming language. It's on the people writing the files to make sure their editors use a matching setting.

For the case of using indentation as a block separator, the number of "spaces" a tab should be is irrelevant. All you need to know is if there's a tab or a space, and that the indentation matches perfectly with the indentation of the previous line. If it doesn't then either it's a new block starting (and there are ways to check if that's what's expected) or the current block is ending (which is harder to check for but still possible). It would also be easier if you don't allow wild mixing of tabs and spaces.

Sooo many issues can be prevented by not using an indentation scheme of tabs or spaces.  I've had editors mess up my Python indentation when the editor saves the file.  I like the idea of substatement markers, which reduces tab based indentation issues.

My suggestion is to store the counts of spaces and tabs in separate variables, without attempting to convert tabs to spaces.
It is important to note that tabs and spaces are distinct characters, and this awareness can be advantageous. Tabs might even shown depending on the previous line in some editors
In Python, where indentation is used to define blocks of code, it is imperative to avoid mixing spaces and tabs, even if they appear visually similar in size. Combining spaces and tabs in indentation must result in an error, which says "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation."
For example, this code indicates that error.
def nothing():
    print("Nothing") # 4 spaces
    print("Nothing") # 1 tab

Same for this one.
def nothing():
     print("Nothing") # 1 space 1 tab 1 space
     print("Nothing") # 1 space 1 tab 1 space


This doesn't really answer what was asked. It covers some related topics, but fails to address "how much space". (What would you do with the count of tabs as far as counting indentation goes?)

Come to think of it, changing "to store the counts of spaces and tabs in separate variables" to "to track spaces and tabs separately" would make this seem more like an answer to what was asked, if the intent is that the indentation be measured as the pair [number of spaces, number of tabs]. It's just that when you specify storing something in a variable, I'd expect there to be more processing afterwards (like converting the number of tabs to a number of spaces, as the question asked for).

thanks you @aria It worked for me. I now count space and tab in two variable and compere with previous count value
